# Heroku and database management for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting really close to putting up my first app. However, I'm worried that because I'm so new, I won't know how to manage my database properly.

What's the best practice for managing a database on heroku? As in, backups for example. What if I really screw up something? Can I edit information like usernames, email addresses for users, etc directly in heroku or do I still do that from my terminal?

Comment: How to pick the best bucket of water in the ocean? You're managing a Postgres instance under a Rails stack. The Heroku backup options are self-explanatory. They're just pg snapshots. You should already have followed the Heroku recommendation to develop with a local Postgres. Therefore you have a test database where you can answer your own questions about by-hand edits. Nearly all the Rails and pg tools available locally are there in the Heroku CLI.

Answer (score 0):

As Gene mentioned above, you will use [pg backup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) to back up your db. You can do this manually, but you can also [schedule backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups).

You can easily access the rails console on heroku. Docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#console

Gook luck rolling your your first app!